# Image upload button div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

How do I turn the div with id "uploadWrapper" from this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmRfL/) into a button that can upload images - basically doing the same as `<input type="file">`. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - DUE TO ANSWERS RECEIVED**

How can I show a preview of the image in the place of the div with the blue background when someone uploads an image, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmRfL/2/)

Comment: Please see my answer, it has code examples and demos on how to achieve the appropriate effect.

Comment: Plupload allows you to submit the image upload onto your server, and get back the uploaded image location, which you can then display where ever on your page you want.

Comment: I can't see how you can preview images without reloading using Plupload

Comment: With reloading? Do you mean without reloading?

Comment: Sorry, edited. Example: http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy to do as one would imagine, and some browsers prevent triggering file uploads from untrusted elements automatically for security purposes.

I recommend using a third party file upload plugin, such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), or faking a custom button using progressive enhancement (invisible file upload button, with a custom graphic under it (of course not the most flexible of solutions) as described here:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/

---

Plupload events allows you to hook into the events that might occur during ajax file upload, and do stuff with the upload info. See this page on examples of what response data you might get:

http://www.plupload.com/example_events.php

You can get response data like this:

```
id=p16in5el9ne2fc1rd08120in081
name=denim.png
size=20623
loaded=20623
percent=100
status=DONE
target_name=p16in5el9ne2fc1rd08120in081.png
```

And of course you can modify what the server returns on a successful upload, to be able to get the full absolute URL to the uploaded image.

After you have this data, you can hook into it and switch the image doing something like this (with jQuery):

```
// Called when a file has finished uploading
FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
    $('#id_of_the_image').attr('src', 'uploads/' + file.target_name);
}
```

Comment: Using Plupload is smart since it allows you to support file uploads in a very easy way while supporting many browsers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/kM9aa/1/

Preview: Like Justin Satyr said, there's no way using plan HTML/JS to preview the chosen image unless you upload it to your server and use the uploaded image's URL.

Comment: This does not work in IE8. It just shows the far right edge of the browse button.

Comment: Hmm.. Well.. Lets just say that -1 was uncalled for.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you use Flash, Silverlight, or an Active-X object. Browsers lock down all file browsing operations.

You can appear to do this by making the `<input type="file" />` invisible but over a button so that when the user clicks the "button", they are actually clicking the `input`.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your second question, to preview the image, you would need to post it to your server and then point your `img`'s `src` to an image path on your server.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you look at the `src` of the image preview, you'll see it's on the dondedportes.es server.